# Another asymptotic of integral depending on a parameter:

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, definite-integrals, asymptotics, oscillatory-integral

*(I want to apologise in advance for this messy integral)*

Consider the following integral :

$$ I(x) = \int_0^\infty\frac{\sinh(2e^{(\alpha_1-x)}\sin(\alpha_2-y)).\sin(2e^{(\alpha_1-x)}\cos(\alpha_2-y))}{e^{2πy}-1} \, dy $$

Here,

\begin{align*}
\alpha_1(x,y) &= 0.5\log(x^2+y^2)(x-c)-y\tan^{-1}(y/x) \\
\alpha_2(x,y) &= 0.5\log(x^2+y^2)y+(x-c)\tan^{-1}(y/x)
\end{align*}

And $c$ is a constant.

> I want to know the nature of "(sharp) upper bound" on $I(x)$ as $x\to\infty$ ?

How should I start?

( Is it true that $I(x)=o(x^\epsilon) $ for every $\epsilon>0$ ?)

Any advice on guessing of the possible growth is welcome.

Comment: You have a singularity (for all $x$) at $y=\frac{1}{2\pi}$.  The numerator doesn't look right - it seems to missing a ).

Comment: @herbsteinberg, I guess that what you actually intended is $ y = 0$. For that, it seems to me that this singularity is removable because $$\sin(\alpha_2 - y) \sim y \left( \log(x) + \frac{x-c}{x} - 1 \right) \qquad \text{as} \quad y \to 0 $$ for each fixed $x \neq 0$.

Comment: I stand corrected.